# Extreme point of the unit ball in H(U)

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

An extreme point of a convex subset $C$ of a vector space $X$ is a point which can not be expressed in the form $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$, with $a,b\in C$ and $0<\lambda<1$.

For an open subset $U$ of the complex plan, $\mathbb C$, we denote by $H(U)$ the set of all holomorhphic functions on $U$. The norm on $H(U)$ is the usual $\|.\|_\infty$ norm.

What are the extreme points of the unit ball in $H(U)$?

**The unit ball in $H(U)$ is the set $\{f\in H(U): \|f\|_\infty\leq 1\}$**

Comment: $\|\,\|_\infty$ is not a norm on $H(U).$

Comment: @zhw: Are you sure? Maybe you mean, it is not a Banach space under this norm?

Comment: It's a norm on $H^\infty(U).$

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: If $A={\Bbb C}\setminus U$ contains at most two points then $B_1(H(U))$ consists of constants only. So assume $|A|\geq 3$ and let $\phi:U\rightarrow {\Bbb D}$ be a conformal bijection with the unit disk. On the unit disk a set of extremal points are $e_{n,\theta}=\theta z^n$, $n\geq 0$, $|\theta|=1$. And $e_{n,\theta} \circ \phi$ are then extremal points in $B_1(H(U))$. There are however functions in $B_1$ that are not generated by these extremal points.

Comment: Is your first claim true? The restriction of an entire function to $U$, belongs to $H(U)$?

Comment: Why the functions $e_{n,\theta}$ are extermal?

Comment: Sorry, corrected. I meant in the unit ball. For the second Q: Write $e_{n,\theta}=t \phi+(1-t)\psi$ and use Cauchy's formula for the $n$'th coefficient in the Taylor formula  to deduce that both $\phi$ and $\psi$ has to be the same. It is a bit more tricky to see that $e_{n\theta}$ are the only extremal points.

Comment: Why $e_{n,\theta}$'s are the only extreme points?

Comment: $|A|\ge 3$ implies $U, \mathbb D$ are conformally equivalent?

Comment: I don't think your characterization is correct. I remember this: The extreme points of $H^\infty(\mathbb D)$ are the functions in the closed unit ball of $f\in H^\infty(\mathbb D)$ such that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log (1-|f(e^{it})|)\, dt = -\infty.$$ Here $f(e^{it})$ is the radial limit boundary function, which exists for a.e. $t.$

Comment: @zhw.  Thanks. Yes, I get the point. If $|f(e^{it})|$ takes the value 1 sufficiently often (notably not discrete) then it can not be generated by the polynomials. If you have a ref for the precise statement then perhaps you should post an answer? I'll just correct mine to say that I got a subset of extremal points,... [And yes, the Riemann sphere minus at least 3 points is conformally equiv to the disk]

Comment: @H. H. Rugh: There is a simpler proof: If $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$, then by the equality $\sum |a_n|^2r^{2n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta$, hold for $r<1$, it will be evident that if for one coefficient, $|a_n|=1$, then the other coefficient should be zero. If we have $|a_n|<1$, for all $n$, then choose $b_n$ such that $|a_n\pm b_n|<2^{-n}$, so $r(z)=\sum (a_n+b_n)z^n$ and $s(z)=\sum (a_n-b_n)z^n$, both belong to $B_1(H(U))$ and $f=\frac12(r+s)$.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan Your proof for the $|a_n|< 1$ part is not correct.

Comment: Agree. The first part seems a fine proof of extremality of $z^n$ but for the second you may have difficulties ensuring $r,s\in B_1$ (and it seems indeed to be false in general).

Comment: @H. H. Rugh It is clear that $r,s\in B_1$, since $$|r(z)|,|s(z)|\leq\sum|a_n\pm b_n|<\sum 2^{-n}=1$$ for $z\in \mathbb D$.

Comment: If you could choose such $b_n$, then $|a_n|\leq \frac12 (|a_n+b_n| + |a_n-b_n|)\leq 2^{-n}$ which certainly need not be the case.